# Contour Line and Surface Matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, surface

I want to produce a surface plot with a predefined contour line on the surface, in Matlab. I have already produced the plot in Mathematica, and want to create the equivalent figure in Matlab.

With the following functions I defined a surface

```
k2[G_, V_] = Sqrt[G]*Exp[-V];
k1[G_] = Sqrt[G]*Exp[-10];
L1[G_, V_] = -0.5*(k1[G_] + 2*k2[G, V]) + 0.5*Sqrt[k1[G_]^2 + 4*k2[G, V]^2];
```

and a parametric curve over the surface

```
hike=ParametricPlot3D[{10, 0, 0} + {x^2, x, -(1/L1[10 + x^2, x])}, {x, 0, 12},PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]];
hikeHeight=ParametricPlot3D[{10, 0, 0} + {x^2,x, -z*(1/L1[10 + x^2, x])}, {x, 0, 12}, {z, 0, 1},PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray], Mesh -> None];
```

Then I plot the surface and the contour line together:

```
surf= Plot3D[-1/L1[G, V], {G, 10, 100}, {V, 0, 12}];
Show[surf, hike, hikeHeight, AxesLabel -> {G, V,Z}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

What is the process for evaluating the function and producing the same plot in Matlab?

This how far i get with my matlab attempt

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);
curvX=diag(X);
curvY=diag(Y);
curvZ=diag(Z);

nn = 401;
xi = linspace(-3.0, 3.0, nn);
yi = xi;
[xi, yi] = meshgrid(xi, yi);
zi = interp2(X, Y, Z, xi, yi, 'spline');

figure()
surf(xi, yi, zi,'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'interp')
colormap(parula)
alpha 0.7
hold on
surf(diag(curvX),diag(curvY),diag(curvZ),'LineStyle', 'none')
```

[image]

the surface and the parametric curve are obviously not the same but the idea is the same to plot an slice of the surface

Comment: Show us what you got! Please, do add what you tried, this is not a coding tranlating service! Also, that is what, Mathematica?

Comment: Sometimes it is, sorry :)

Comment: @DylanRichardMuir I hope you did it for the fun!  Let's not encourage people too much to paste their codes, in general. Good answer btw

Comment: It was a relaxing meditation for me :) In general, it's not always obvious how to translate from a symbolic language like Mathematica to one like Matlab where you have to handle the discretisation and functional evaluation explicitly.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I was clue lees on how to do this on matlab, in the edited version of the question I add how far i get with my dummy attempt on matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by defining the functions, as inline, vectorised function handles:

```
k2 = @(g, v)sqrt(g).*exp(-v);
k1 = @(g)sqrt(g).*exp(-10);
l1 = @(g, v) -.5 .* (k1(g) + 2.*k2(g, v)) + 0.5 * sqrt(k1(g).^2 + 4.*k2(g, v).^2);
```

Now we need to define a mesh, since Matlab isn't smart enough to do automatic discretisation like Mathematica:

```
nMeshPoints = 50;

vfG = linspace(10, 100, nMeshPoints);
vfV = linspace(0, 12, nMeshPoints);
[mfG, mfV] = ndgrid(vfG, vfV);
```

Ok, now we can evaluate the surface over the mesh, and make a surface plot:

```
hSurf = surf(mfG, mfV, -1./l1(mfG, mfV));
shading interp;
hold on;
hSurf.FaceAlpha = 0.5;
```

Now we need to build and plot your parametric line, also via explicit discretisation:

```
vfX = linspace(0, 12, nMeshPoints);
vfZ = linspace(0, 1, nMeshPoints);

vfLX = 10 + vfX.^2;
vfLY = vfX;
vfLZ = -(1 ./ l1(10 + vfX.^2, vfX));

vfLHeight = vfLZ .* vfZ;

plot3(vfLX, vfLY, vfLZ, 'r-');
plot3(vfLX, vfLY, vfLHeight, 'k-');
```

Now we can make the plot a little more beautiful:

```
xlim([10 100]);
ylim([0 12]);
zlim([0 20000]);
caxis([0 20000]); 
xlabel('G');
ylabel('V');
zlabel('Z');
view([60, 30]);
```

The result: not quite as beautiful as Mathematica, but at least equivalent.

[image: Surface plot with contour]

Comment: hint 1: `caxis([0 20000])`. Also, I'd say the black line should have single `Z` value.Something like `plot3(vfLX, vfLY, zeros(size(vfLX)), 'k-');` or `plot3(vfLX, vfLY, ones(size(vfLX))*min(Zsurf), 'k-');` being `Zsurf` the surface's minimum

Comment: Anyway, just random hints, I like MATLAB plots :P

Comment: @AnderBiguri RE the black line: I also thought so, but the definition in the question doesn't seem to have constant Z...